# get data dynamically in select tag in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, selection

below is my code, it doesn't work. I want to get the list of data in select tags dynamically from the database. but data is not shown on the list. it is blank. please help me

**views**

```
              <'<thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Products</th>
                    <th style="width: 31%">Qty</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td scope="row">1</td>
                    <td style="width:60%">
                <form method="POST">
                       <select name="products" id="products"   class="form-control">
                          
                         <option value=""></option>

                       </select>'>
```

**Controller**

```
      <' public function getproducts(){

   $id=$_POST['product_name'];
   $mydata['products']=$this->lg->select_product($id);
   echo json_encode($mydata);
}
```

'>

**Models**

```
     <' public function select_product($id){

 $r= $this->db->select('*')->from('products')->WHERE('id',$id)->get();
 $rs=$r->result_array();
 return $rs;
             }
```

'>

**js**

```
        <'$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#products').change(function() {
          var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].id;
         $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
               url:'<?php echo FORMURL;?>Adminlogin/getproducts',
               data:{id : id},
               dataType:'json',
               success:function(data)
         {
           $('#price').text(data.product_price);

           $('#qty').text(data.product_qty);
        }
   });
 });'>
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

remove dataType JSON

```
public function getproducts(){
   $id = $this -> input -> post('id');
   $mydata['products']=$this->lg->select_product($id);
   echo json_encode($mydata);
}
```

Comment: but i have not to send this form  anywhere, I want only get data in select tag

Comment: where, in controller